# Customizing Web Page HTML/CSS And Saving It

Tags: google-chrome, html, css

Is there any way to customize web-page HTML/CSS and saving it? For example, if I go to *Developer Tools* (Inspect Element) on Chrome and change page CSS styles (making some  to be hidden), it would show me those changes, but after refresh of the page it would go to the default state.

Not sure if this is even possible but maybe someone will know?

Comment: Are you trying to change some one elses website

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if there's a tool that can track your changes and save them for next time, but your can use a [User scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) extension to your browser and create a script that will alter the page you want.

You can alter the CSS/HTML inject JS etc. You can set rules on which site/page the script will run, and at which point of the loading process of the web page.

The two most popular user script managers I know are:

- [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) (Firefox)
- [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) (Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to customize Webpages in HTML and CSS and JS if you have saved the pages locally in your computer and made changes using any text editing tool like notepad and then running the html and css file in your local computer or if you want to reflect the changes in website then you need to run that html and css using server side JS for example with the help of node.js. I think that the problem you are facing is due to the reason that you are making changes temporarily in CSS and HTML file in your client computer which could not be reflected in the remote computer running the html and css of it.
If you want more clarification please respond me I will try to explain in detail.

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the web page and select "View page source" to view its HTML code.
Copy the HTML code and paste it into a text editor like Notepad or Sublime Text.
Make your desired changes to the HTML code.
Save the file with a ".html" extension.
To apply your CSS changes, create a separate ".css" file and link it to the HTML file using a link tag.
Open the HTML file in a web browser to see your customized page.
Note: The changes you make will only be visible on your computer and won't be reflected on the original website. To publish your changes, you'll need to upload the files to a web server.
If you want more clarification please respond me ***BrainXskill***  will try to explain in detail.

Comment: I think the OP us trying to change a website thsts not his.